Are these two ways of tracing the indices of the Riemann curvature to obtain the Ricci tensor the same?
Both Wikipedia and Ivo Terek's notes (p. 6) define the Ricci curvature first as the trace $\mathrm{Ric}(X,Y) = \mathrm{tr}(V\mapsto R(V,X)Y)$. In an abstract index notation, this is
$$R_{ij} = R_{kij}{}^k,$$
i.e. the trace of the first index with the fourth. However, they then go on to write the Ricci tensor as the trace of the first index with the third. Ivo writes
$$R_{ij} = g^{kl}R_{kilj},$$
and Wikipedia has
$$\mathrm{Ric}_{ab} = R^c{}_{bca}.$$
Is the trace of the first index with the fourth really the same as the trace of the first index with the third? After all, the curvature tensor is not symmetric in its last two indices, but skew-symmetric (at least when the connection is torsion-free). So shouldn’t we get an additional minus sign as below?
$$R_{ij} = R_{kij}{}^k = R_{kijl}g^{kl} = -R_{kilj}g^{kl}$$

why is the trace formula equivalent to contracting the 1st and the 4th index? (I would say it's the 1st and the 3rd)

$\mathrm{tr}\big(V\mapsto R(V,X)Y\big) = \sum \langle R(E_k,X^iE_i)Y^jE_j,E_k\rangle = \sum X^iY^j R_{kij}{}^k.$ Also, Ivo writes $R_{ij} = R_{kij}{}^k$. That’s tracing the first index with the fourth. Do you disagree with it @user8268?

@user8268, every geometer has their own personal convention of how to arrange the indices. Since I prefer, for purely aesthetic reasons, having the superscript first instead of last, I've adopted the following convention: First, the curvature tensor at $x \in M$ is a $\operatorname{End}(T_xM)$-valued $2$-form $R$. In other words, given any $X, Y$, $R(X,Y)$ defines a linear map \begin{align*} R(X,Y): T_x & \rightarrow T_x\ Z &\mapsto R(X,Y)Z. \end{align*} With respect to a frame $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$, I prefer to write the $2$-form indices last. So $$R(e_i,e_j)e_k = R^l{}_{kij}e_l. $$

The Ricci curvature for me is $\operatorname{Ric}(e_j,e_k) = R^i{}jik.$ More recently, I've also started writing $R(e_i,e_j)e_k = e_lR^l{}_{kij}$. In other words, if a superscript and subscript are being summed over, I write the factor with the subscript first. This is consistent with the standard convention for multiplying matrices where the superscript is the row index and the subscript is the column index. This allows you to write many differential geometric formulas using matrices and matrix mulplication.

You're correct that those two contractions differ by a sign. This reflects the fact that there are two inequivalent ways of designating the index positions in the Riemann curvature tensor.
The Wikipedia article on Ricci curvature doesn't say what index convention they're using for the curvature tensor, but if you refer to the article on the Riemann curvature tensor, you'll see that their convention is
$$
R^\rho{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = dx^\rho(R(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)\partial_\sigma),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
R(\partial_j,\partial_k)\partial_i = R^\ell{}_{ijk} \partial_\ell.
$$
Then their definition of $Ric(Y,Z)$ as the trace of $X\mapsto R(X,Y)Z$ yields their formula
$$
Ric_{ab} = R^c{}_{bca}.
$$
They don't ever claim that $R_{ij} = R_{kij}{}^k$.
On the other hand, the notes by Ivo Terek define the curvature tensor indices by
$$
R(\partial_j,\partial_k)\partial_i = R_{jki}{}^\ell \partial_\ell,
$$
which differs from the Wikipedia convention by a sign. Then Terek's definition of the Ricci tensor is the same as Wikipedia's, but now it leads to the index formula
$$
R_{ij} = R_{kij}{}^k,
$$
which appears on page 8 of Terek's notes. Given the sign difference between Wikipedia's and Terek's conventions for the curvature tensor, this means that their definitions of the Ricci tensor agree.
But then Terek goes on to write, on the same page,
$$
R_{ij} = g^{kl}R_{kilj},
$$
which is just a mistake, because it's inconsistent with his earlier formula.
It's not surprising that you found this confusing.

Thanks for catching the mistake, Jack! I have corrected it in the notes and adjusted the formula for the scalar curvature later in the same page (just hit refresh if you don't see the changes right away). Anyone reading anything I wrote who thinks I might have made an error is more then welcome to email me with questions, and I will do my best to clarify things. I'm in the process of changing institutions, so my webpage and these texts might be down for a while (between May and July while I sort things out), but I will leave a new link in my profile here whenever I get it ready.

@IvoTerek: Great. Sorry I didn't think to write to you directly about the error -- I always appreciate it when people write to point out errors in my books.

@IvoTerek, I believe this mistake propagated in other formulas further down in your notes. For example, on p. 15 when calculating the Ricci for the Schwarzschild half-plane, you write $R_{tt} = \Omega_{tr}((dr)^\sharp,\partial_t)$, but according to your new formula on p. 6 ($R_{ij} = \Omega_{lj}((\theta^l)^\sharp,E_i)$), $R_{tt}$ should be equal to $\Omega_{rt}((dr)^\sharp,\partial_t)$ and not $\Omega_{tr}…$. Similarly for $R_{tr}$, and $R_{rr}$. In any case, I thank you for your notes as they were very enlightening despite this error.

You are correct. There are only 4 non-zero contractions of the Riemann tensor due to it's anti-symmetric properties. They are;
$$R^i_{jik}=\text{Ric}_{jk}$$
$$R_{j}^{\;i}{\ }_{ki}=\text{Ric}_{jk}$$
$$R^{i}_{jki}=-\text{Ric}_{jk}$$
$$R_{j}^{\;i}{\ }_{ik}=-\text{Ric}_{jk}$$
So, the definition that $\small R^i_{jik}=\text{Ric}_{jk}$ is a simply a convention which differs only by a sign.
